# highcharts additional title opinion

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to ask an opinion about adding an additional title to highcharts header.

Highcharts provides 2 (title and subtitle) by default, but what we are trying to do is to add one more title (dek) between them. 
we solved it by adding breaks **but fixing spacings killing me.**

Also, we have specs and they should be strictly followed (every px counts).

**PROBLEM :** 
 There are different properties that affecting titles such as `chart.spacing[0]`, `title.margin`, svg `y` properties that we are trying to manipulate manually.

Also in our case titles are dynamic, they could be structured in different ways

- include only Title
- only dek (in-between title & subtitle)
- only subtitle
- Title & dek
- Title & dek & subtitle
- title & subtitle
- dek & subtitle

In addition to that, we produce different types of charts. So it's a lot of conditions. Same thing with credits, we have multiple lines, but text doesn't wrap automatically (as it does for headers), I had to manually count how many characters could fit for particular width(styled mode).I feel it's not supposed to be this way and I really need to figure out how to solve it. 
That would be great to get an opinion from someone's who actually works in highcharts. Thank you!

 **Here is an example**:
[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `useHTML` proeprty to `true` and style the part of the title as you want:

```
title: {
    useHTML: true,
    align: 'left',
    text: `
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
        <span class="titleSpan">Integer quis pharetra tellus. Cras tincidunt libero id dignissim convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</span>
    `
},
subtitle: {
    align: 'left',
    text: 'Sed aliquam ligula in pretium lobortis.'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ad3reo8b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.useHTML

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpful! Another question I have is how to control space between title and subtitle, let's say I want 20px? In the example above you have ~ 15px. Is there a better way than using subtitle.y property? @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Sabira Davletshina, You can use only title with multiple spans. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hqfegr29/

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate that! Using allowHTML and having everything in one title works great for 'digital' charts, but when I am trying to download svg it doesn't apply styles as it says here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html-in-highcharts. what would you suggest in my situation? And thank you again! @ppotaczek

Comment: particularly interested in spacings

Comment: Hi @Sabira Davletshina, I am glad that I could help. Please check the result with inline styles: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uzLx3gr/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek sorry, I forgot to say that I need svg support . Here is a simpler version of what I currently have. I decided not to use 'useHTML', but instead decided to manipulate "dy's", and control 'Title margin' using 'title.margin' property. But every time I change title (as I mentioned before they dynamic) margin changes as well. So my question is, how do I make margin persistent no matter how many lines of titles I have. To measure margin in the browser window I use 'Page Ruler Extension'.

Comment: Here are 2 examples with about 4px margin difference. http://jsfiddle.net/sabira/r0zvouyp/41/ -19px margin;
http://jsfiddle.net/sabira/r0zvouyp/43/ - 15px margin

Comment: @Sabira Davletshina, The title margin is not dynamic, so if you want to move some text, you also need to increase the marign.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help.